# Código de upload de imagens não envia gif para a pasta

Tags: php, mysql

Estava tentando enviar imagens para o banco de dados, e a melhor forma era salva-las em um diretório e enviar somente o nome para o MYSQL, só que quando eu envio uma gif, ela n vai para o diretório mas vai normalmente para o mysql...

```
<?php 
require ('connect.php');
mysql_connect("$host", "$usuario", "$senha");
mysql_select_db("$bd");
if ($_POST['enviar']) {
    $nome = $_POST['nome'];
    $usuario = $_POST['usuario'];
    $senha = $_POST['senha'];
    $foto = $_FILES['foto']['tmp_name'];
    $extensao = strtolower(pathinfo($_FILES['foto']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
    $nome_imagem = uniqid();
    $caminho_imagem = "imagens";
    $search = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE usuario='$usuario'");
    $checar = mysql_num_rows($search);
    //if ($checar == 0) {
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO usuarios(nome,usuario,senha,foto) values('".$nome."','".$usuario."','".$senha."','".$nome_imagem.".".$extensao."')");
    move_uploaded_file ($foto, $caminho_imagem."/".$nome_imagem.".".$extensao);
    //}

}
```

Este é o código de cadastro...

Comment: então, você deve estar com problema de permissão na pasta. coloque um IF para verificar se fez o upload e depois faça a inserção

Comment: if(move_uploaded_file ($foto, $caminho_imagem."/".$nome_imagem.".".$extensao)) { mysql_query("INSERT INTO usuarios(nome,usuario,senha,foto) values('".$nome."','".$usuario."','".$senha."','".$nome_imagem.".".$extensao."')");
 }